# Line spacing in title

Tags: spacing, titles

I am creating a LaTeX document with a header as follows.

[image]

I am however trying to get author slightly closer to the date so that it looks a little better.

Currently the LaTeX equivalent is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=0.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\hrule
\begin{flushright}
    Author
\end{flushright}
\begin{flushleft}
    \huge \textbf{Title}
    \hfill
    \normalsize Date
\end{flushleft}
\hrule

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use `flushright`. Better use `\hfill` to get the stuff you want flushed to the right.

Answer (score 3):

Using a table, you can get the following. Using `minipage`s is also possible, especially if the title gets longer.

[image: ashishTitle]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=0.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{b{#1}}
\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
    \toprule
    & Angry Ant \\
    \bfseries\LARGE Ameisens\"aure is not an english word, but who cares?& \today \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{3em}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \rule{\linewidth}{.8pt}\medbreak
    \parbox[b]{.5\linewidth}{\bfseries\LARGE Ameisens\"aure is not an english word, but who cares?}
    \hfill\parbox[b]{.3\linewidth}{\raggedleft Angy Ant \par \today}
    \rule{\linewidth}{.8pt}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{3em}
\noindent
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you first type the title and then put Author and Date in a table, you can have full control of the vertical distance between then. Here I used `10mm`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=0.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\hrule
\noindent\textbf{\huge Title}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[b]{r@{}}
  Author\\[10mm]
  Date
\end{tabular}
\hrule\strut\newline

\lipsum[1]
\strut\newline

\hrule
\noindent\parbox[b]{0.8\linewidth}{\textbf{\huge Very long title that needs more than one row in the title}}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[b]{r@{}}
  Author\\[10mm]
  Date
\end{tabular}
\hrule\strut\newline

\end{document}
```

In the second case when the title spans more than one row I put it in a `\parbox` to align its bottom baseline with the Date baseline. That can of course be done for the single line case also.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

here's a slightly different approach.  it takes into account that if there is more
than one instance of this structure in your document, and only one of those has
descenders in the last line, the vertical spacing will be uniform.

like the other answers, it provides an option for a multi-line title.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=0.3in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\hrule
\vspace{4pt}
\noindent{\huge\bfseries Title\strut}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[b]{r@{}}
  Author\strut\\
  Date
\end{tabular}
\hrule
\bigskip
some text here

\bigskip
\hrule
\vspace{4pt}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[b]{.7\textwidth}
\huge\bfseries\raggedright\strut
This title is very long and requires more than one line\strut
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[b]{r@{}}
  Author\strut\\
  Date
\end{tabular}
\hrule

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]